# Fastest way to check the number of occurences in a list in java

Tags: java

I have a list and each element of the list contains an array of Points.

```
List<LineString> lines = new LinkedList<LineString>()
```

The list looks like this :

```
object1 - ((2.36937, 48.82156, NaN), (2.36935, 48.82159, NaN), (2.36931, 48.8217, NaN))
object2 - ((2.35855, 48.83217, NaN), (2.35851, 48.83218, NaN), (2.35846, 48.83219, NaN), (2.35842, 48.83218, NaN), (2.35838, 48.83217, NaN))
object3 - ((2.35841, 48.832, NaN), (2.35846, 48.83199, NaN), (2.35852, 48.832, NaN), (2.35857, 48.83202, NaN), (2.3586, 48.83205, NaN), (2.35861, 48.83208, NaN), (2.35861, 48.83212, NaN), (2.35859, 48.83214, NaN))
```

And so on and so forth. I would like to count the occurrences of the first element of each object in all the objects of the list.
Which is the fastest way to do that?

The list has almost 70000 objects and my way of implementing takes too much time to provide the results because i am using a O(n*n) implementation:

```
for (ListIterator l = validLines.listIterator(); l.hasNext();)
{
        int aux1=0, aux2=0;
        LineString validLine = (LineString) l.next();

        for(ListIterator m = (ListIterator) lines.listIterator(); m.hasNext();)
        {

                LineString compare = (LineString) m.next();
                for(int i=0;i<compare.getCoordinates().length;i++)
                {
                   if( validLine.getCoordinates()[0] == compare.getCoordinates()[i] )aux1++;
                   if( validLine.getCoordinates()[validLine.getCoordinates().length-1] == compare.getCoordinates()[i] ) aux2++;
                   if(aux1 >1 || aux2>1)break;

                }
        }
```

}

Is there any way i can make it faster?

Comment: What is `LineString`? It is certainly not an array.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, corrected the mistake.

Comment: Why do you want the fastest way? Is it that you've figured a way out, and that is not really performant enough? If not, have you benchmarked it, and assured that it is really a bottleneck of your application? You'll probably get a quick and better reply, if you post your current working solution (as you're asking for faster approach, we assume you have one working solution), else this question will soon get closed.

Comment: Before you start thinking about the fastest solution you should consider providing a *working* solution. Or, maybe you should start with thinking about what it actually should do. Neither your verbal explanation nor your code is capable of telling it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're looking for, but if I am guessing correctly, something like the below might run in average O(n) time:

```
Map<MyElement, Integer> nOcurrences = new HashMap<MyElement, Integer>();
for(ElementType element : myList) {
  if(nOccurrences.contains(element) {
    nOcurrences.put(element, nOcurrences.get(element) + 1);
  } else {
    nOcurrences.put(element, 1);
  }
}
for(ElementType element : nOcurrences.keySet()) {
  System.out.format("%s occurs %d times.%n", element, nOcurrences.get(element));
}
```

For obvious reasons you'll have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` accordingly.